# Firefox extension: Refer to object defined in bootstrap.js from XUL file

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to contribute to [a Firefox extension I use](https://github.com/jvenant/passff), but I have no idea what I'm doing :)

I've got a dialog powered by a XUL document to gather some data from the user. That's all fine and good. But when the user confirms the dialog, I need to call a function defined on an object that's defined in my `bootstrap.js` file.  Is that possible to do directly? e.g., in the XUL file:

```
<prefpanes id="my-pane" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <script>
    function myCallback() {
      PassFF.myAction(); // PassFF is undefined here
    };
  </script>
  <prefpane>
    <button id="my-button" oncommand="myCallback();" />
  </prefpane>
</prefpanes>
```

If that's not possible, is it possible to register a callback when I open the document in the first place? Something like this:

```
var dialog = window.openDialog("chrome://passff/content/mypane.xul",
                               "my_pane_name",
                               "chrome,titlebar,toolbar,modal");
dialog.addEventListener('close', function(event) {
  PassFF.myAction(); // PassFF is defined here, but the event doesn't fire
});
```

I've tried things like importing the `bootstrap.js` script in my XUL document with another `script` tag, adding another "content" line to the manifest to expose the file, different events (unload, command, click) but couldn't figure out any of these approaches either.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can use, for example, platform observer mechanics.

this is "signals.js" file (module):

```
let EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["addSignalListener", "removeSignalListener", "emitSignal", "signalNamePrefix"];


const {utils:Cu, classes:Cc, interfaces:Ci, results:Cr} = Components;


function genUUID () {
  let uuidgen = Cc["@mozilla.org/uuid-generator;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIUUIDGenerator);
  if (!uuidgen) throw new Error("no UUID generator available!");
  return uuidgen.generateUUID().toString().replace(/[^-a-z0-9]/ig, "");
}


const signalNamePrefix = "signal-"+genUUID()+"-";
const obs = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);


let observers = {};

function addSignalListener (name, cback) {
  if (typeof(name) !== "string" || !name) throw new Error("invalid signal name");
  if (typeof(cback) !== "function") throw new Error("callback function expected");
  // check if already here
  if (cback in observers) {
    let names = observers[cback];
    if (name in names) return; // nothing to do
  } else {
    observers[cback] = {};
  }
  let observer = {
    observe: function (subject, topic, data) {
      topic = topic.substr(signalNamePrefix.length); // remove prefix
      if (data && data.length) {
        try {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (e) {
          Cu.reportError(e);
          return;
        }
      } else {
        data = null;
      }
      cback(topic, data);
    },
  };
  obs.addObserver(observer, signalNamePrefix+name, false);
  observers[cback][name] = observer;
}


function removeSignalListener (name, cback) {
  if (typeof(name) !== "string" || !name) throw new Error("invalid signal name");
  if (typeof(cback) !== "function") throw new Error("callback function expected");
  // find observer
  let names = observers[cback];
  if (names === undefined) return; // nothing to do
  if (!(name in names)) return; // nothing to do
  try { obs.removeObserver(observers[cback][name], name); } catch (e) {}
}


function emitSignal (name, data) {
  if (typeof(name) !== "string" || !name) throw new Error("invalid signal name");
  data = (typeof(data) === "undefined" ? null : (data !== null ? JSON.stringify(data) : null));
  obs.notifyObservers(null, signalNamePrefix+name, data);
}
```

sample use:

```
Components.utils.import("chrome://myext/content/signals.js");

dump(signalNamePrefix+"\n");
addSignalListener("mysignal", function (signame, data) {
  dump("MYSIGNAL("+signame+"): "+data+"\n");
  for (let [k, v] of Iterator(data)) dump(" ["+k+"]=["+v+"]\n");
});

emitSignal("mysignal", {any:42, data:[669], here:"wow!"});
```

here just import "signals.js" in your "bootstrap.js", and add signal listener. then import "signals.js" in your dialog js, and emit signal with the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I tried this, but I think I'm not importing the script correctly in the XUL document (maybe I need to add a line for it in my chrome.manifest file?). Any tips on that front?  (you can refer to the project file structure in the linked GitHub page -- the files are in `src` -- I tried adding signals.js file to `modules` directory, then adding a line in the XUL document to import the script: `<script src="chrome://passff/content/signals.js" />`, and a line in the chrome.manifest: `content   passff  modules/`, but I get an error in the console at startup from the manifest line)

Comment: 1. you can't load module from XUL file, you have to do what i shown in sample: import it **inside** your .js file. i.e. you have to create .js file, move your javascript code from XUL to that .js file, and import `signals` there. **that** new js file should be loaded with `script` tag in XUL.


2. there is already defined `passff` content in manifest, no need to add another one. just use "chrome://passff/content/modules/signals.js"